# Web Scraping with BeautifulSoup with python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, decode

I'm scraping with BeutifulSoup via python on :
i woud like to extract the title name "Don Ḳarlos: gresṭe drama der ṿelṭ"
i get this as ouptput: "Don á¸²arlos: gresá¹­e drama der á¹¿elá¹"

my code:

```
resp = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(resp.content)
element = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[2]/text()')
t = element[1]
print(t)
```

the html:

```
  <dt>Title</dt>Don Ḳarlos: gresṭe drama der ṿelṭ<dd>Additional title: Don Ḳarlos</dd>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you on Windows?  That looks like the UTF-8 encoding of that non-ASCII character.  You need to encode that string in a way that matches what your terminal epects.

Comment: Hi Tim,
I'm on ubuntu 18.04.
i tried to encode it i cant encode the tree0xpath

Comment: And how are you outputting it?  Like many people, you haven't shown us the most important parts.  Show us everything involved.

Comment: i edit the question. i would like to assign it to variable and print it.

Comment: Please try `resp.encoding = 'utf-8'` immediately after your first line.  And by the way, if that works, it means the web site you're reading has not correctly declared its character set.

Comment: *AttributeError: module 'html' has no attribute 'fromstring'*. Please add all `import`s to your [mcve].

Comment: `tree = html.fromstring(resp.content.decode())` or `tree = html.fromstring(resp.text)` should work…